# Unknown method (for me) to obtain the value of a variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This are notes from a NN. This is one of many steps to solve differential equations with separate variables. In this step NN does following:

$$g_1(y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \sin\left(\frac{n\cdot\pi}{b}y\right)$$

And then, to obtain $A_n$ he does:

$$A_n = \frac{2}{b}\int_0^b g_1(y)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{b}y\right)dx$$

Why? Or what is the name of this method?

Thx

Comment: What does NN mean?

Comment: NN for No Name. Just someone

Comment: I'm slightly confused about your notation.  Why does $g_1(y)$ not have a $y$-term on the RHS?  Also, is $\delta x$ supposed to be $dx$?

Comment: This is the "Fourier trick."

Comment: auch! sorry ... i will fix it. The 'x' should be a 'y' and de $\delta$ should be a $dx$

Answer (score 3):

This is a (slightly garbled) Fourier sine series.  Here $g_1(x)$ is supposed to be a  (sufficiently nice, e.g. piecewise smooth) function defined on the interval $[0, b]$ with $g_1(0) = g_1(b) = 0$.  We then expand it in  the series $g_1(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(\frac{n \pi}{b} x)$ where $a_n = \frac{2}{b} \int_0^b g_1(x) \sin(\frac{n \pi}{b} x) \, dx$.

Comment: Yess! Seems you are right! Thx a lot all of you for your time. I'm not a registered user, and because of that i can not mark the answer as 'accepted', if some admin can do it, it would be nice.